# Como salvar o IP de quem visitou meu site em um arquivo de texto?

Tags: php, arquivo, editor-de-texto, ip

Estou utilizando o código abaixo, mas só grava "::1" no arquivo.

```
<?php 
$arquivo = "ips.txt";
$file = fopen($arquivo,"a"); 
$string = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']  . "\n";
$fp = fwrite($file,$string);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Será que é porque estou no localhost?

Comment: Dependendo das configurações do seu servidor pode até ser. Pode parecer besteirea, mas ecoar **$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']** retorna a mesma coisa?

Comment: Você pode testar se tiver outro aparelho na rede. Pode até ser seu celular. Entra na página que você está fazendo e faz um eco como o Bruno falou.

Comment: Sim, retorna "::1" também.

Comment: ::1 é o IPv6 de localhost

Comment: Já pensou em usar o http://www.google.com/intl/pt-BR_ALL/analytics/

Comment: @AlexSchmitt Eu conheço, mas no momento preciso desse conhecimento.

Comment: Testei em um host free o código e funciona. Eu segui a resposta do @chambelix, mas toda vez que eu atualizo a página o mesmo ip é gravado novamente. Como gravar somente se não já estiver lá?

Comment: Se o usuário estiver usando proxy, você teria que combinar algumas verificações com, `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, entretanto, eles pode ser facilmente manipulados enquanto `REMOTE_ADDR` não pode. Leve em conta que alguns programas fornecem um IP novo para navegação "anônima", e nesse caso o IP **não** seria o real IP do usuário mesmo usando `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Comment: Verdade, para questão de identificação é incerto, no entanto para fins estatísticos deve servir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

utilizando o código colocado na pergunta ...
lembrei-me agora desta forma...

```
<?php
    $arquivo = "ips.txt";
    $string = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']  . "\n";
    // ao usar FILE_APPEND para adicionar ao ficheiro estamos a colocar no fim do mesmo
    // e com o LOCK_EX trata das gravações concurrentes que podem acontecer
    file_put_contents($arquivo, $string, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

::1 é a notação IPv6 para 127.0.0.1

Comment: Testei em um host free e os códigos e funcionam. Eu segui sua resposta, mas toda vez que eu atualizo a página o mesmo ip é gravado novamente. Como gravar somente se não já estiver lá?

Comment: aconselho a utilização de uma base de dados. Caso contrário terá de ler o ficheiro e procurar pelo IP respectivo, claramente uma pior solução.

Comment: Vou fazer isso mesmo, mas preciso saber trabalhar com arquivos para outras coisas.

Comment: Como eu faria a leitura?