# Salvo o IP do visitante em arquivo de texto, mas como não salvar novamente se já estiver lá e como fazer a leitura?

Tags: php, arquivo, ip

Usei a resposta dessa pergunta para salvar o IP em um arquivo de texto:
[Como salvar o IP de quem visitou meu site em um arquivo de texto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31968/como-salvar-o-ip-de-quem-visitou-meu-site-em-um-arquivo-de-texto)

É o seguinte, eu quero criar um botão tipo o "curtir" para que os alunos curtam aqueles que eles acham que são os melhores professores.

Mas como impedir que um aluno que já curtiu curta novamente?

Eu imaginei que tendo um arquivo de texto para cada professor, dentro de uma pasta, com o número de ips que curtiram seria uma solução. No banco de dados poderia ficar muito extenso ou dá no mesmo?

Sei que posso usar os plug-ins do Facebook, por exemplo, mas e se as cores do meu site não combinam com nada do face  ou se por exemplo esse sistema funciona numa intranet? Enfim eu quero saber a lógica para se conseguir esse objetivo.

Comment: Use um banco de dados. Não faz sentido usar um arquivo para isso.

Comment: Qualquer um pode curtir ou somente usuários registrados?

Comment: Somente os cadastrados.

Comment: Mas assim, no caso de um artigo, qualquer um poderia curtir, cadastrado ou não.

Comment: IP não serve para controlar essas coisas, IPs mudam, se for na internet geralmente é fácil resetar o moden e ter um IP novo para poder curtir de novo, se for intranet pode acontecer de mais de uma pessoa usar o mesmo computador então só uma conseguiria votar.

Comment: Eu usaria o e-mail do usuário então, mas aí só posso controlar os que são cadastrados. E para os artigos?Acho que o melhor é isso mesmo, só curte quem for cadastrado, afinal só curte com Facebook quem tem conta...

Comment: Mas não vai ficar grande no banco de dados? Professor "A", emails: x, t, y, z... Professor "B", emails: c, d, y, z...

Comment: Bancos de dados são feitos pra isso :)

Comment: :3 É mesmo! Vou trabalhar nisso.

Comment: Usar IP não é bom.
E para isso eu usaria o consagrado par: variável de sessão (como os cookies) e um SGDBR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o pessoal já comentou nos comentários, é melhor você usar algo diferente do IP para marcar a votação, mas se mesmo assim você quer verificar se determinado IP já votou use algo do tipo:

```
$arquivo = "ips.txt";

function has_voted($ip) {
  // o método file retorna um array com cada linha do arquivo
  $rows = file($arquivo);

  // basta verificar se o ip do usuário já está gravado no arquivo.
  in_array($ip, $rows);
}

if (!has_voted($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
  vota(); // seu método para votar

  // grava o ip do cara que acabou de votar no arquivo de ips
  // http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31970/2321
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']  . "\n";
  file_put_contents($arquivo, $ip, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Algumas considerações:

a) Grave a seu arquivo como json, pois poderá sempre utiliza-lo com outras linguagens. Pode ser algo assim :

```
{"ipss":["111.111.111.111","222.222.222.222"]}
```

e salve como arquivo_nome.json. Também pode usar valores separados por virgulas(CSV), mas eu prefiro o json, que acho mais descritivo.

b) Quanto mais ips tiver, mais lenta será e execução da função, porque onde vamos agir é uma coleção, então conforme a coleção aumenta, mais dados temos apara agir. As bases de dados são otimizadas para isso.

c) não incluí a abertura e gravação do arquivo, pois já sabe como fazer.

```
function check_ip($novo_ip)
{
    $sip = NULL;

    //aqui abre o arquivo json
    $ips = '{"ipss":["111.111.111.111","222.222.222.222"]}';

    //verifica se o ip é válido
   if (!filter_var($novo_ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) 
        return "Não pode votar";

    //passa json para array
    $o = json_decode($ips,TRUE);

    //já votou, não pode votar mais
    if(is_array($o['ipss']) && in_array($novo_ip, $o['ipss']))
        return "Não pode votar";

     $o['ipss'][]="$novo_ip";

     //cria miolo do json
     foreach ($o['ipss'] as $value) 
     {

            $sip .='"'.$value."',";
    }

    //aqui eu coloquei return mas pode colocar para gravar o aquivo atualizado
    return '{"ipss":['.trim($sip,",").']}';

}
```